# Determining Linear System given Solution Set

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be the following subset of $\mathbb R^3$
$$\{(2+3s,2-s,s)\vert s\in \mathbb R\}$$

1. Write down the equation of 3 different planes in $\mathbb R^3$ such that the points of intersection of the 3 planes is set S. Justify your answer.
2. Write down the equation of four different planes in $\mathbb R^3$ such that the planes intersect in exactly one point and the only point of intersection belongs to $S$. Justify your answer.

For 1)

I know that the general solution is $x=2+3s,y=2-s ,z=s,s\in\mathbb R$, to find the first plane $P_1$, since $z=s$ then $x=2+3z \iff x-3z=2$ and $y=2-z\iff y+z=2$.

Subsituting $x-3z=2$ and $y+z=2$ gives me $P_1:x-y-4z=0$

Next, since $s=2-y$, then $x=2+3(2-y)\iff x-6+3y=2$ and $z=2-y \iff z+y=2$

Subsittuting $x-6+3y=2$ and $z+y=2$ gives me  $P_2:x+2y-z=6$

Next, since $s=\frac{x-2}{3}$ then $y=2-\frac{x-2}{3} \iff 3y-6+x=2$ and $z=\frac{x-2}{3} \iff 2=x-3z$

Subsittuting $3y-6+x=2$ and $2=x-3z$ gives me $P_3:y+z=2$

This is the method that I have been using, does anyone have a faster and more painless method? So far in Linear Algebra I have learnt Echelon Forms, Gaussian Elimination, Matrices, Spans and Subspaces.

For 2)

I decided to find the Reduced Row Echelon Form of the 3 Planes, which can be derived from the set $S$.

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -3 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I wanted the point of intersection to be $(2,2,0)$, since that is the easiest when $s=0$, so I decided to add in a row into the matrix which is $z=0$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -3 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I am honestly not sure if $z=0$ is the answer that this question is looking for, so I decided to add both Row 1 and Row 2 to obtain this:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -3 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Hence $P_4:x+y-z=4$

Is there a better way to do this in general? And is there a easier way to derive the linear system given the solution set only? Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just about write down the solution to these problems directly if you use the point-normal form of the equation of a plane. If $\mathbf p_0$ is some known point on the plane and $\mathbf n$ is a vector perpendicular (normal) to it, then a point $\mathbf p$ lies on the plane iff $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf p=\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf p_0$.

We can read directly from the defining equation of $S$ that it’s a line through the point $\mathbf p_0=(2,2,0)$ with direction vector $\mathbf v=(3,-1,1)$. The planes that contain this line contain $\mathbf p_0$ and have normals perpendicular to $\mathbf v$. We can find three such normal vectors immediately: $(1,3,0)$, $(1,0,-3)$ and $(0,1,1)$ (can you see how I derived these vectors from $\mathbf v$?). This leads immediately to the equations of three planes that intersect in $S$: $$\begin{align} x+3y &= 8 \\ x-3z &= 2 \\ y+z &= 2. \end{align}$$ For the next part of the question, we just need to find a plane that intersects $S$ at only one point. A simple choice is the plane through $\mathbf p_0$ with normal $\mathbf v$: $3x-y+z=4$.

Now, there is a way to solve these problems by finding the null space of a certain matrix, but I think the above is much easier, as you requested.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your help! Could I ask if the 3 normals $v$ are derived from crossing any 3 points with the direction vector?

Comment: @Derp I just find these orthogonal vectors by inspection, but they also happen to be the cross products of $\mathbf v$ with the unit standard basis vectors.

Comment: Undetstood! Thank yoi!

Comment: @Derp Hmm... I just noticed that you had a second question there at the end. A short answer to that one is that you can convert in either direction between parametric representations of a flat (point, line, plane, &c) and a system of linear equations by finding the basis of the null space of a matrix. You’ve no doubt already seen how to do this when starting with a system of equations; it works in the other direction as well.